# Linkedin V2 UGC posting

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin V2 API. When i posting a message has new lines it returns this error

```
1. Hello how are you all. (this will be posting fine to linkedin)
2. Hello 

   how are you all ( this returns error)

 posting code:
 $share_content='{
            "author": "urn:li:person:'.$profile_id.'",
            "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
            "specificContent": {
                "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                    "shareCommentary": {
                        "text": "'.$postcontent.'"
                    },
                    "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
                }
            },
            "visibility": {
                "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
            }
        }';

{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Error parsing request body to json Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (com.linkedin.data.ByteString$ByteArrayVectorInputStream); line: 7, column: 44]","status":400}
```

if the post has any double quotes. It will also returns this error.

Comment: That’s what you get for trying to _manually_ assemble JSON, instead of preparing the appropriate _data structure_ and then using json_encode on that …

Comment: you say i should create php array first then json_encode?

Comment: Yes. (Replacing the newlines in $postcontent with an actual literal \n would probably also get the job done ... but it would still be fundamentally wrong to begin with, IMHO. You do not create JSON “by hand”, if that is avoidable.)

Comment: Thank You I will try that. due to  the manual assembling json i get the error when post has double quotes?

Comment: No, you get the error because of the newlines - exactly as the error message _already said_ …

Comment: @04FS Now its working.Thank You